# Replace Text in a column based on values from a lookup table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a imported table of data from Excel (ImportedTable example) that has data and some "units" jumbled together and trying to "filter" out the units (LookupTable example) to clean it up. The LookupTable can have almost 20 different values, and the ImportedTable is about 2000 records.

Trying to select the text from a column without the values from another table. Example:

LookupTable:

```
"Id"  | "Name"
'1'   | '% time operational'
'2'   | 'KGal'
'3'   | 'Gallons'
...
```

ImportedTable:

```
"Id"  | "Text"
'1'   | 'SomeText here % time operational'
'2'   | '500 KGal'
'3'   | '1.05 Gallons'
'4'   | '105,000'
'5'   | 'TestTextKGal'
...
```

Desired Result:

```
'SomeText here'
'500'
'1.05'
'105,000'
'TestText'
```

I know this doesn't work but wanted something like this to work:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE([Text], (SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM LookupTable), '')))
FROM ImportedTable
```

And those lookup values are removed from the "Text" in every record in ImportedTable, in a select statement (not actually removing them from the table).

Comment: Join the two tables on the id column then perform the replace using the text and name columns.

Comment: Sorry, that's slightly misleading on my part. The "Ids" in those two tables won't line up, 1 has about 20 records and the other has 2k records. But the bigger table doesn't have a foreign key or anything like that to get me to the LookupTable.

Comment: Traverse lookup table with a recursive cte, replacing text on each step.. https://dbfiddle.uk/2OsEl5q0

Comment: Can there be multiple `LookupTable` matches for a single row in `ImportedTable`? Overlapping `LookupTable` values? Overlapping matches in `ImportedTable`? You've already specified that you don't want word breaks to be significant, `'TestTextKGal'` matches `'KGal'`, so [`'Scunthorpe, North Lincolnshire, England'`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) should match `'Thor'`, unless it is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross join the two tables and take the `MIN()` of the result of making all the substitutions:

```sql
SELECT
  i.[id], MIN(TRIM(REPLACE(i.[Name], l.[Name], ''))) AS Name
FROM ImportedTable i
CROSS JOIN LookupTable l
GROUP BY i.[id]
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BvXT5rU3).

Note that the convenient use of `MIN()` here only works when removing text from the *end* of text. It works because `MIN()` considers text to be "less" if characters are removed from the end, eg `'TestText'` is "less than" `'TestTextKGal'`.

Note also the use of `TRIM(...)` instead of `LTRIM(RTRIM(...))`.

Comment: This worked best for my use case. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solution will remove all text from the second tabe, which has text FROM the first independent of the position

I Expect that all pattern will only once occur, for multiple you must
You need to repeat the first CTE until no more matches are found

the perfomance can be improve when you replace the `LIKE CONCAT('%' , t1.[Name] , '%')` with a full text search.

```
WITH CTE aS (SELECT
t2.[id],  REPLACE(t2.[Text],t1.[Name],'') resttest
FROM Table1 t1 CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
WHERE t2.[Text] LIKE CONCAT('%' , t1.[Name] , '%'))
SELECT * FROM CTE
  UNION ALL
SELECT  [Id],[Text] FROM Table2 
  WHERE [Id] NOT IN (SELECT [Id] FROM CTE )
ORDER BY Id
```

| id | resttest |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | SomeText here |
| 2 | 500 |
| 3 | 1.05 |
| 4 | 105,000 |
| 5 | TestText |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4HHugH1T)

Answer (score 0):

Just another option which will support **MULTIPLE** occurrences of lookup values  within the imported text .

Here, we convert your table into a JSON string and then do a Global Search & Replace via the Lookup table.  Note the descending order of `len([Name])` ... this will avoid any collisions (values within values).

**Example**

```
Declare @S nvarchar(max) = (  Select * from ImportedTable for JSON Path )
 
Select @S=replace(@S,[Name],'')
 From  (Select top 10000 * 
         From  LookupTable 
         Order By len([Name]) desc
        ) A

Select *
 From  OpenJSON(@S)
 with ( Id int
       ,Text varchar(500)
      )
```

**Results**

```
Id  Text
1   SomeText here 
2   500 
3   1.05 
4   105,000
5   TestText
```